# Documentation for poker-engine

Tags: python, documentation, poker

I am interested in developing a poker game. For this purpose I found [poker-engine](http://pokersource.sourceforge.net/). But with all googling and searching the projects sites I couldn't find any documentation on its API. 
Do you know any place where I can find a documentation on how to use it, or do I need to read the whole code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well did you download `poker-engine`?

There is an examples folder in the distribution that documents the main functionality. The file is called `simple.py`

Comment: The sources are actually C. You can 'bind' to other languages they say, like java, or Python so it seems as well.

Comment: yeah I downloaded it and looked at the example... but e.g. I want to know if I can add some callback function when new cards are dealt etc. and I can't read that from the example.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find any docs, good luck with your search :) Might be crawling through some source code!